# Override pear Package

Tags: php, pear

I'm using Math_Finance pear package locally. I made a modification to some file included in the package, this made my calculations work. Now I migrate my project to a web shared hosting and asked to install the same pear package. However I'm unable to perform the same modification I did locally because is a shared hosting.

My question is: is there a way to override or just include the file that was modified? I don't want to copy all files in the package to my public_html directory but I'm afraid that this is the only solution.

Thanks

Comment: If it's a fix you might want to send in a patch for that. If it's just new functionality. Why not extend Math_Finance with your own class and overwrite the specific functionality in there?

Comment: @tlenss Why not answering this? Overwriting is a **good** idea!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the method they used for representing the path to the included files this may work.

Assuming the original file is in

```
/usr/local/share/php/PEAR/Statistics/Cool.php
```

In your site mirror the PEAR and save your version as

```
/mywebroot/library/PEAR/Statistics/Cool.php
```

Then prepend the path to your library directory into the include paths

```
ini_set("include_path", "/mywebroot/library".PATH_SEPARATOR.ini_get("include_path"));
```

Now when including your version will be found prior to PEAR's.

Comment: modifying the include_path might not being necessary, but you have to make sure that you require *both* files: `Finance.php` and `Finance_FunctionParameters.php` from the location inside `public_html`

Comment: True if the path that he requires already proceeds pear or he gives an absolute path to the file he included and lets all of the other pear dependencies come in via include path resolution

Comment: This was the best option, extending the class would also needed to extend other classes like numerical methods. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could send in a patch if it's a bug fix. If it's just added functionality. You could simply overwrite some functionality of the Math_Finance class by extending it. (thanks for the tip @hek2mgl ;)

```
Class Math_Finance {

   public function someMethod() {
      // original logic
   }

}

Class My_Math_Finance extends Math_Finance {

   public function someMethod() {
      // change some of the needed logic
   }

}
```

Comment: Yeah overwriting bugs or extending functionality in a subclass is a good idea, unless the original package hasn't been fixed! +1 :)

Comment: Including the PEAR files in the project is fine as well :) This is just the way i would do it. ty for the +1!

Comment: As an active member of the PEAR community, I would urge you to share your patch up-stream to the PEAR QA team as the Math_Finance package is no longer actively maintained, especially if this fixes a bug. To report a bug or request a new feature to this package you can do so  at https://pear.php.net/bugs/report.php?package=Math_Finance

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to copy all files in the package to my public_html directory but I'm afraid that this is the only solution.

Yep! that's the solution. But what is so bad with that? We are talking about 2 additional php files ;) :

```
Math/Finance.php
Math/Finance_FunctionParameters.php
```

Place them in a folder inside your application, let's say `lib`. Then make sure, that you import *both* files from this location:

```
require_once 'lib/Math/Finance.php';
require_once 'lib/Math/Finance_FunctionParameters.php';
```

Comment: Btw, would be nice to see your patch :)

Comment: the problem is that Math_Finance also includes Math_Numerical classes and there are plenty of them

Comment: Ok, I see, then @Orangepill's suggestion: modify the include_path, might be a good advice in this situation. do you understand what I mean? The suggestion of (at)tlenss would be good as well (maybe best)

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with pear as well and had to change to remove the pear requirement - here is the fork from original repo without pear

https://github.com/hashmode/Math_Finance